# Update the program to print results everytime

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

This program is used to fetch offer details from Amazon with offer percentage

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import argparse

#Comment out these 3 lines and change the searchterm variable, if you do not wish to use argparse version
my_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Return BF Amazon Deals')
my_parser.add_argument('searchterm', metavar='searchterm', type=str, help='The item to be searched for. Use + for spaces')
args = my_parser.parse_args()

searchterm = args.searchterm

s = HTMLSession()
dealslist = []


url = f'https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k={searchterm}&i=black-friday'

def getdata(url):
    r = s.get(url)
    r.html.render(sleep=1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.html.html, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def getdeals(soup):
    products = soup.find_all('div', {'data-component-type': 's-search-result'})
    for item in products:
        title = item.find('a', {'class': 'a-link-normal a-text-normal'}).text.strip()
        short_title = item.find('a', {'class': 'a-link-normal a-text-normal'}).text.strip()[:25]
        link = item.find('a', {'class': 'a-link-normal a-text-normal'})['href']
        try:
            saleprice = float(item.find_all('span', {'class': 'a-offscreen'})[0].text.replace('£','').replace(',','').strip())
            oldprice = float(item.find_all('span', {'class': 'a-offscreen'})[1].text.replace('£','').replace(',','').strip())
        except:
            oldprice = float(item.find('span', {'class': 'a-offscreen'}).text.replace('£','').replace(',','').strip())
        try:
            reviews = float(item.find('span', {'class': 'a-size-base'}).text.strip())
        except:
            reviews = 0

        saleitem = {
            'title': title,
            'short_title': short_title,
            'link': link,
            'saleprice': saleprice,
            'oldprice': oldprice,
            'reviews': reviews            
            }
        dealslist.append(saleitem)
    return

def getnextpage(soup): 
    pages = soup.find('ul', {'class': 'a-pagination'})   
    if not pages.find('li', {'class': 'a-disabled a-last'}):
        url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk' + str(pages.find('li', {'class': 'a-last'}).find('a')['href'])
        return url
    else:
        return

while True:
    soup = getdata(url)
    getdeals(soup)
    url = getnextpage(soup)
    if not url:
        break
    else:
        print(url)
        print(len(dealslist))  


df = pd.DataFrame(dealslist)
df['percentoff'] = 100 - ((df.saleprice / df.oldprice) * 100)
df = df.sort_values(by=['percentoff'], ascending=False)
df.to_csv(searchterm + '-bfdeals.csv', index=False)
print('Fin.')
```

I am needed to show the complete result as a single list or as an array.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\loxku\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\main24.py", line 69, in <module>
    df['percentoff'] = 100 - ((df.saleprice / df.oldprice) * 100)
  File "C:\Users\loxku\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5989, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'saleprice'
```

Comment: @Jonas De Schouwer: Please find the Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\loxku\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\main24.py", line 69, in <module>
    df['percentoff'] = 100 - ((df.saleprice / df.oldprice) * 100)
  File "C:\Users\loxku\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5989, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'saleprice'

Comment: What do you expect to happen if `products` list is empty? Causing `dealslist` to be empty? More specifically, please debug your parser better. Amazon generally prevents web scraping like this, and goes against Terms of Service

Comment: @OneCricketeer: If the products list is empty it must return Not Available result. Just needed to know where I am missing out. So an updated code working code will be helpful.Also, I am using it for personal use.

Comment: "Must return Not Available" - Your code does not do this, therefore you're getting the shown error instead

Comment: I recommend you `print(len(dealslist))` before `df = pd.DataFrame(dealslist)`, outside the else statement, and then you'll see the issue more clearly

Comment: Great Help @OneCricketeer, If you could provide working code it will be really helpful!

Comment: Fixing the error shown is easy. Doesn't mean your program will work the way you expect. It could just not print anything at all, since the dataframe would be empty (and has no columns that can be referenced as your error says). Do you really need pandas? What's wrong with `csv.DictWriter`?

Comment: Great Idea, @OneCrickeeter